# Removing Copper from drinking water by Electrolysis? What to keep in mind?

Tags: water, metal, electrolysis, purification

The drinking water in my flat contains a lot of copper. Although the amount of copper is around the allowed limit 2mg/l I would prefer to reduce it.

I know that it is at this value from a paid analysis in a dedicated laboratory.

Edit: *The copper was introduced into the water when passing through long copper pipes inside the house. But because it is not my house, I cannot do anything about this aspect.*

In my childhood I played around a lot with Electrolysis in general, producing funny gas, plating things with copper etc. So why not remove the copper from drinking water this way? (I know filters with activated carbon can help, but please lets think about Electrolysis here).

Lets assume a glass pot with 1l of drinking water containing 2mg of copper.

The task is to reduce copper content by an electrolytic procedure without increasing the content of other adversary substances thus without decreasing the "quality" of the treated water.

Lets take these data as a working example:

[image: Example cation and anion contents of the water to be treated]

If it is possible at all, what electrode materials and arrangements, voltage, current, duration might bring me towards the defined target?

Comment: Hydrolysis isn't electrolysis... And it would be much easier to reduce it, for ex. with vitamin C.

Comment: Thanks, in the title I used the wrong word, Electrolysis was meant.

Comment: @Mithoron: What is the outcome after adding vitamin C? In what form would the copper exist afterwards? Nanoparticles? How to get it out of the reservoir?

Comment: Well, yeah, maybe this wasn't the best idea, but neither is electrolysis. Simple boiling removes quite a bit of stuff from water. If purification is really needed, it's rather reversed osmosis in use.

Comment: Is it not possible to have the water pass through steel wool. Copper ions would react with metallic iron according to : $\ce{Cu^{2+} + Fe ->  Cu  +  Fe^{2+}}$. This would replace copper ions by iron ions, which are not toxic at such concentrations.

Comment: Hm, ok, could be enforced with a few volts, a graphite-anode and the iron as cathode?
Hoped to have some monitoring (current measurement?) to see when finished....

Comment: If the given data apply, copper is mostly present as species $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$; it's probably actually saturated.